# Vagrant doesn't run on Windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vagrant

I've added Add AWS Dummy box to vagrant
But when I create a server, I get the following error.

```
$ vagrant up aws
Bringing machine 'aws' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> aws: Box 'dummy' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
aws: Box Provider: virtualbox
aws: Box Version: >= 0
==> aws: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> aws: Adding box 'dummy' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
aws: Downloading: ./boxes/dummy.box
aws:

An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Couldn't open file /C:/my_folder/boxes/dummy.boxhere
```

NOTE: This works fine on a Mac. The issue is only in windows

Comment: you have something wrong in your Vagrantfile, I think you have something on `config.vm.box_url`

Answer (score 0):

You might need to manually add the box and then run vagrant up.

```
vagrant box add dummy https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/raw/master/dummy.box
```

> After installing the plugin (instructions above), the quickest way
>   to get started is to actually use a dummy AWS box and specify all the
>   details manually within a config.vm.provider block. So first, add the
>   dummy box using any name you want:

Comment: I did this. Still doesn't work. I get the same error